# Null response from API in Angular

Tags: c#, json, angular, asp.net-core, angular2-services

Learning Angular 2 and building an app with .Net Core
I've an API from which `json` response is passed to Client Side. In my `Angular2` service, used `Observable` to read the response and pass it to my `component` and then to `view`.
Tested in `PostMan` and my API is responding expected output. I'm sure the service has some issue which is taking time to resolve.

API :

```
[HttpGet]
    public List<MovieFields> Get()
    {
        path += @"\Data\MovieSource.json";
        string jsonSource = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
        List<MovieFields> source = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MovieFields>>(jsonSource);
        return source;
    }
```

Json c# class :

```
public class MovieFields
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Service :

```
export class MoviesService{

constructor(private http: Http) {
}

getMovies() {
    return this.http.get('api/Movies')
        .map(res => <Array<MovieProperties>>res.json());
}
```

}

Component :

```
export class AllMoviesComponent implements OnInit {

private movieProp: Array<MovieProperties>;
ngOnInit() {
    this.moviesService.getMovies()
        .subscribe(ban => this.movieProp = ban);
}
```

Angular Json Interface :

```
export interface MovieProperties {    
Id: string;
Title: string;
```

}

and finally my JSON:

```
 [
{
  "Id": "1",
  "Title": "Olympus Has Fallen"
},
{
  "Id": "2",
  "Title": "Man of Steel"
}  ]
```

**Answer : edited my `service` as below**

```
getMovies(): Observable<MovieProperties[]> {

    return this.http.get('api/Movies')
        .map(this.extractData)
        .catch(this.handleErrors);
}
private extractData(res: Response) {
    let data = res.json();
    return data;
}
```

thanks `Sajeetharan`

Comment: Please dont angular2 questions as angularjs .

Comment: @32teeths sorry

Comment: Nothing to be sorry , Just so that you know . I havent started with ng2 yet :D

Comment: Why are you wasting cpu cycles (and memory) by deserializing your json file and then serializing it again? You can directly stream the json file. by `return PhysicalFile(path, "application/json")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method inside the service should be like this,

```
getMovies() : Observable<MovieProperties[]>{
    return this._http.get('api/Movies')
        .map((response: Response) => <MovieProperties[]>response.json())
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

private handleError(error: Response){
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
}
```

Comment: are these are same `Array<MovieProperties>` or `MovieProperties[]`?? because my API returns `List`

Comment: MovieProperties[] would be fine

Comment: mapping at `component` is not working.`this.moviesService.getMovies()
            .subscribe(ban => console.log(ban));` logs the response from `service` but when I assign to my local variable `this.movieprop` returns null to view

Comment: this.moviesService.getMovies()
    .subscribe(ban=> this.movieProp =ban),
    error => this.errorMessage = <any> error;

Comment: No luck. Still same result... anyway adding error handling is not mandatory right??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141762/discussion-between-vino-m-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 1):

```
export interface MovieProperties {    
id: string;
title: string;
}
```

Changing the case like this worked for me.